# What is the AUX_IN and CD_IN connection on old Soundblaster sound cards?

Tags: input, sound-card

What is the AUX_IN and CD_IN 4-pin connection on old Soundblaster sound cards? The card's model is CT4170. Here is an example
[image]

I think its some sort of input. Is there any schematic which tells me which pin is what? There was also a connector on one of those inputs with three wires. Here is how it was connected[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are analog inputs for a CD drive and whatever auxiliary device such as another CD drive.

The pinout is Left Ground Ground Right.

Comment: thank you so much! I wonder if i could use the sound card without a computer. I've found this schematic on the internet about the pins on the card: https://cdn-0.enacademic.com/pictures/enwiki/73/ISA_Bus_pins.png

Comment: Without a computer? So with what device instead of a computer? And for what use?

Comment: not connected to anything. Just the 12 and 5 volt pins and connect an old CD player to that CD_IN port

Comment: @SmokingDieselGR for what? The audio out of an old CD player is already analog audio. What's the purpose of having the soundcard?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeaah right

Comment: At most it could drive speakers with the built in amp. If the audio paths from those inputs to output are selected and with large enough volume.

Answer (score 1):

Those are audio inputs.  The sound card can record them or mix them into the speaket output, or record and mix to output at the same time.

"AUX" is "auxilliary."  Any line level signal you'd like to connect.

"CD_IN" is for connecting the audio output of the CD drive.  It is just a line level input, but the mixer will show it as CD so that you know which one it is.

AUX and CD are wired differently.

AUX:

Look closely at the markings beside the connectors, and you'll see "L" and "R."  That's "left" and "right."  The signal goes to the outer pins.

Connect the left and right signals from a line level source (or headphone cable from your phone) to the appropriate L and R pins.

Connect the ground to the middle pins.  Either one, or both.  It doesn't matter.

The connections are "LGGR."

CD:

There are several ways these were wired.  Later boards used the same scheme as AUX.

Yours appears to be "LOGR." That's "left," "open," "ground," and "right."  "Open" means there's no connection.

[This page has descriptions of many common PC audio connections.](https://www.vogonswiki.com/index.php/CD_audio_connectors)